# App freezes on splash screen for some users

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play-services, splash-screen

Some users report an issue: they launch the app, the splash screen appears, but nothing else happens. Splash screen just stays on without ANR or errors.

I can't see any logs because no loggers were initialized yet, and I don't even know if the `onCreate` method was called.

Important notes:

- 99% of users don't experience this
- users that report such issue say that it's persistent - they can't use the app at all
- some users say if they launch google play store first and then launch app - it works fine, but without that step it always freezes at the splash screen, so they have to launch google play store each time before launching the app

To send any data anywhere I need to initialize a bunch of dependencies, but looks like it doesn't even get to that point. App works fine on millions of devices, but a few thousand users reported this issue. Cannot post application initialization code as it's huge.

Questions:

- What can possibly be the reason of this?
- Where would be the best place to start searching for the bug?
- Is there a way to determine the first line of code where the app is not launching as it should?
- Is there something that the google play store triggers that applications need to launch properly?

Comment: Are you handling all Exceptions from Api correctly? Some retries?

Comment: if there are any exceptions I'm not handing, I'm not aware of them, everything that is known to throw any kind of exception is handled

Answer (score 0):

It was because of `googlePlayStoreAppUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo` check for updates that returns a Task, but sometimes it doesn't actually call nor success nor fail listeners, so we hang forever. Solution was to add RxJava wrapper with timeout and limit waiting time for Google to answer to some reasonable time.
It looks like some devices, like Xiaomi or Honor are not allowing google play manager to check for updates unless explicitly started by the user, so this check should be done carefully.